# Implementing a QtDesigner-like behavior with QtDesigner

Tags: qt, user-interface, drag-and-drop, qt-designer

I want to implement an editing procedure like the one seen in QtDesigner. That is, having a toolbox of available "blocks" and being able to drag them into the working area of program to create a new instance of some sort of editable object (or widget).

I know that I can write it from scratch, but it seems logical that you can create something like QtDesigner within QtDesigner. I noticed that for toolbox they used a combination of Dock Widget and List Widget.

But I struggle to come up with the correct elements for the drag & create behavior.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html. It's quite a lot of work though, so if you can live with widget promotion, I'd do that instead.

Comment: Why won't you embed the workspace of and tool boxes from Qt Designer itself? It's a part of Qt, you can and should use it just as any other part of Qt :)